# Temps surcomposés

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, temps-grammatical, temps-surcomposés

Les temps surcomposés sont peu documentés dans les livres de grammaire.

Dans quels cas doit-on ou peut-on utiliser les temps surcomposés en français ? Pouvez-vous donner des exemples concrets de leur utilisation ?

Comment: Un lien vers la page wikipédia sur les [Temps surcomposés](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temps_surcompos%C3%A9).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Si tu (ou n'importe qui) te donne la peine d'en faire une synthèse en réponse, je pense que ça répond entièrement à la question. [Le domicile des mots](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/surcomp.html) peut servir aussi.

Comment: [Another way](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/8843/358) to answer your question.

Comment: Un exemple dans une autre question : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19276/understanding-ils-auraient-eu-bient%c3%b4t-mang%c3%a9-tout-le-pauvre-patrimoine

Answer (score 12):

[D'après l'académie](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#86_strong-em-temps-surcomposs-em-strong) :

> Les temps dits surcomposés servent à marquer des faits antérieurs et accomplis par rapport à des faits qui, eux-mêmes antérieurs par rapport à d’autres faits, s’exprimeraient par les temps composés correspondants.
>
> À la voix active, on forme l’indicatif passé surcomposé en ajoutant le présent de l’auxiliaire avoir au participe passé de l’auxiliaire avoir ou de l’auxiliaire être (selon les verbes) du passé composé :
> « *elle a fait cela* » donne « *quand elle a eu fait cela* » ;
> « *ils ont fait cela* » donne « *quand ils ont eu fait cela* » ;
> « *elle est partie* » donne « *quand elle a été partie* », et
> « *ils sont partis* » donne « *quand ils ont été partis* ».

[Le domicile des mots](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/surcomp.html) indique :

> [Ces tournures] sont plus présentes dans l'Est et le Sud, dans les milieux populaires et ruraux. Elles peuvent être utilisées pour marquer un aspect délimité, achevé ou le commencement d'une action épuisée, on peut parfaitement ne pas employer de subordonnée même si c'est la forme la plus habituelle.

Et l'académie de rajouter qu'*on considère généralement cet emploi comme dialectal.*

Par exemple :

- *Dès que j'ai eu écrit la lettre, je l'ai envoyée.*
- *Lorsqu'il a eu déjeuné, il est sorti.*
- *Cette règle, je l'ai eu apprise.*
- *Ça a eu payé.*

<sub>Et pour les extrémistes :</sub>

> <sub>La voix passive se forme selon les mêmes procédés à partir des passifs correspondants : *quand cela a été fait* (passé composé passif) donne *quand cela a eu été fait* (passé surcomposé passif).</sub>
>
> <sub>Mais *cela n'est pas attesté fréquemment dans l'écrit* d'après *Le Bon Usage* (13e éd., § 788 b).</sub>

- *Quand il a eu été terminé, M. Paris en a donné un compte rendu.*