# Quand utiliser un passé surcomposé plutot qu'un plus-que-parfait ?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, temps-grammatical, temps-surcomposés

Je suis conscient de l'existence de [temps surcomposés](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/79/temps-surcomposes). Je me suis réfèré à [Wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/passe%20surcompose), et je suis à la recherche d'[une réponse catégorique](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=515268&page=3&p=4212889#post4212889) à propos du passé surcomposé.

- http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/surcomp.html cite *Discours de la méthode* de Descartes :

  > Sitôt que **j'ai eu acquis** quelques notions générales touchant la physique [...], j'ai remarqué jusqu'où elles pouvaient conduire. »

Pourquoi n'a-t-il pas employé le plus-que-parfait : *sitôt que j'**avais acquis** quelques notions …* ?

- [P. 358 *dans La Méthodologie des sciences morales et politiques, appliquée à la science*…
  de Jean Pierre Cros-Mayrevieille](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=p3RZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA358&dq=%22a+eu+franchi%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=kUzfUofWJoWpiAevqoGABg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22a%20eu%20franchi%22&f=false) :

  > Lorsque la spéculation **a eu franchi** les bornes de la vraisemblance, et est devenue par trop utopique, on s'est borné à en appeler au sens commun qui est l’empirisme de la science; car il a bien fallu que le monde se gouvernât même avec l'ignorance de ses lois.

Pourquoi pas le plus-que parfait : *lorsque la spéculation **avait franchi** les bornes …* ?

Doit-on toujours se servir du passé surcomposé ? Seulement à l'écrit ? À l'oral ?

Comment: Personnellement dans les deux cas j'utiliserais le passé antérieur. (Et je n'irai pas chercher chez un auteur du XVIIième siècle des exemples à suivre).  Mais les temps surcomposés ne font pas partie de mon dialecte et toutes leurs utilisations me font sursauter.

Comment: Les temps surcomposés ne sont jamais obligatoires, ils sont surtout utilisés à l'oral et plus dans le sud de la France où ils n'ont absolument rien de désuets (voir commentaire de @StéphaneGimenez). Voir si ma réponse [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/8843/358) t'aide un peu plus.

Answer (score 3):

Comme le dit le commentaire plus haut, il vaut mieux éviter de prendre des exemples d'auteurs anciens car l'usage a beaucoup changé. Le passé surcomposé est très peu utilisé actuellement. Les phrases avec le plus-que-parfait sont correctes.

Il y a une légère nuance avec le plus-que-parfait : les deux temps servent à marquer l'antériorité par rapport à une action qui est déjà au passé. Néanmoins, le passé surcomposé exprime une action terminée avant l'action principale, alors que le plus-que-parfait peut indiquer une action qui s'est prolongée au-delà.

Comment: Le plus que parfait me gène dans ces phrases.

Comment: Qu'est-ce qui te gêne ?

Comment: Si je savais l'exprimer, j'en ferais une réponse.

Comment: Ça me gène aussi, le plus-que-parfait est un imparfait, or il s'agit dans ce cas d'une action dont justement on souligne l'aspect parfait.

Comment: C'est bien la nuance que je souligne, non ? Je ne vois pas par quel autre temps on peut remplacer le passé surcomposé ici.

Comment: J’utiliserais soit le passé antérieur avec un passé simple dans la principale, soit le passé composé, la structure de la phrase permettant de comprendre l’antériorité.

Comment: Oui, le passé antérieur semble convenir davantage. Cependant, je ne trouve pas que les phrases avec le plus-que-parfait soient incorrectes.

Comment: Perso je viens du sud et la sur-composition ne me gêne pas, je dirais même que c'est la seule qui me parait normale (voire correcte) dans ces phrases. Elle existe spécialement pour ces cas-là (je vais rarement, comme le font certains, jusqu'à l'utiliser avec une antériorité implicite). Autrement il faut se résoudre à utiliser le passé simple dans la principale.

Comment: Si vous pensez que ma réponse est incorrecte, je peux la supprimer.

Comment: Ce n'était que mon avis. Désolé pour le style court qui peut paraître un peu péremptoire, ce n'était pas l'intention. En fait, ce qui nous faudrait dans l'idéal c'est des références, des citations qui utilisent exactement cette structure avec antériorité (j'imagine que le plus courant c'est passé antérieur avec passé simple dans la principale et que peu osent la même structure avec un passé composé).

Comment: Je disais ça sans mauvaise humeur aucune. Il n'y a pas de quoi être désolé :) Les différents commentaires me font douter de la véracité de ma réponse, c'est pour ça que j'ai demandé. Je n'ai malheureusement pas trop le temps de chercher des références. Cela dit, si une autre réponse (et de meilleure qualité) est proposée, je supprimerai la mienne.

Answer (score 0):

je pense que le plus que parfait est à utiliser quand c'est la durée de l'action qui implique la conséquence. Le passé surcomposé, serait que la fin de l'action implique la conséquence, quelque chose d'instantané donc.
Bon, le plus simple est d'éviter ce genre de tournure de phrase, ça évite les problèmes!

Answer (score 0):

Je suis d'accord avec ceux qui trouvent le plus-que-parfait bizarre dans ces phrases. Je ne dirais jamais :
Sitôt que j'avais acquis des notions... , j'ai remarqué....
En fait je dirais plutôt :
Dès que j'ai acquis des notions.... , j'ai remarqué...
c'est une succession de faits passés "de premier plan". L'imparfait a pour effet de mettre l'action "acquérir des notions" au deuxième plan, or c'est le facteur déclenchant donc doit se trouver sur le même plan que l'action "remarquer". Certes on perd la marque d'antériorité, mais celle ci est exprimée par le Dès que (ou sitôt), ce qui me suffit amplement.