# Double past participle / passé antérieur

Tags: temps-grammatical, participe-passé, temps-surcomposés

In my French class last week, we learned about the Passé Antérieur and there was an example in the text that I couldn't figure out. It wasn't the Passé Antérieur, but I didn't know what it was. The example was:

> Aussitôt que j'ai eu fini, je suis partie.

I had never encountered a double past participle, and I was unclear about when to use it and how it relates to the Passé simple/antérieur.  I thought that one would normally say “Aussitôt que j'ai fini, je suis partie” (without the extra “eu”).

Could someone please explain the usage of this double past participle, and why my example isn't correct?

Comment: Tell me if I need to translate my answer below, I can if necessary, but since you read French at uni I suppose it's better you get an answer in French. Don't hesitate to ask your questions in French, we usually appreciate the effort and there are enough of us around to correct any errors.

Comment: "Encore eût-il fallut que je le susse" >;-) Sorry, I just couldn't resist it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il s'agit de ce qu'on appelle un **temps surcomposé**. Certains verbes conjugués avec avoir (c'est plus rare avec être) ajoutent un auxiliaire de plus à un temps déjà composé. Dans un temps déjà composé (ici le passé composé) au lieu de laisser l’auxiliaire au temps simple on le met au temps composé correspondant.

- *j'ai fini* est un  passé composé
- *j'ai eu fini* est un passé composé composé

On emploie un temps surcomposé pour marquer un fait antérieur et accompli (1) par rapport à un fait qu'exprime le temps composé de l'action exprimée en parallèle (2).

(1) → *j'ai eu fini*
(2)  →  *je suis partie*

Les temps surcomposés sont surtout employés à l'oral, du moins en France du Nord (on les emploie plus facilement dans le sud de la France).
En langue écrite on emploie plutôt le passé antérieur, ce qui explique pourquoi tu l'as rencontré dans la leçon sur le passé antérieur :

> Aussitôt que j'eus fini, je suis partie.

**Autres exemples de temps surcomposés**

- Futur surcomposé :

  > Quand j'**aurai eu mangé**, je partirai.
- Subjonctif :

  > Encore eût-il fallu que j'**aie eu allumé** le feu pour que le gâteau cuise.

« <del>*Aussitôt que j'ai fini, je suis partie*</del> » ne serait pas correct pour les raisons de concordance des temps que j'ai indiquées plus haut.
« Je suis partie » indique une action **déjà passée**, et « Aussitôt que j'ai fini » indique une action **future**.

Comment: C'est quand même bizarre de mélanger les temps comme tu le fais. Rien d'incorrect mais c'est un style hybride qui j'avoue me dérange un peu. Sans mélange ça donne « Aussitôt que j'eus fini, je partis » ou « Aussitôt que j'ai eu fini, je suis partie ». De même « Encore aurait-il fallu que j'aie eu allumé le feu pour que le gâteau cuise » ou « Encore eût-il fallu que j'eusse allumé le feu pour que le gâteau cuisît ».

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, pas de mélanges de temps mais **concordance** des temps. « J'eus fini » est un passé antérieur et la leçon du PO portait sur le passé antérieur, donc je suis restée dans ce cadre. On peut aussi bien employer le passé composé que le passé simple dans la principale. (Grevisse « Quand il a été arrivé, il a mangé »). Le passé simple étant quand même plus du registre écrit. Les temps surcomposés sont surtout employés à l'oral et encore pas partout. Quant au subjonctif surcomposé je ne l'emploierai jamais, même à l'oral, mais théoriquement c'est possible.

Comment: Pardon, mais j'ai toujours entendu et lu que les temps composés étaient plus facilement employés à l'écrit qu'à l'oral.

Comment: @user3158: je n'ai jamais entendu ça, le contraire non plus d'ailleurs. L'emploi des temps est assez rigide en français et ils ne sont  pas interchangeables.

Comment: @user3158: Attention ne pas confondre les **temps composés** et les **temps surcomposés** dont l'emploi n'est jamais obligatoire et considéré par certains grammairiens comme "du langage populaire", ils sont peut-être une trace de certains parlers occitans où ils sont plus facilement employés, ce qui expliquerait leur emploi plus fréquent dans le sud de la France. Je n'ai pas trop le temps de rechercher dans mes bouquins mais voici article de revue [scientifique](http://www.persee.fr/articleAsPDF/lsoc_0181-4095_1995_num_71_1_2688/article_lsoc_0181-4095_1995_num_71_1_2688.pdf) avec des éléments.

Answer (score -1):

"Personnellement dans les deux cas j'utiliserais le passé antérieur. (Et je n'irai pas chercher chez un auteur du XVIIième siècle des exemples à suivre). Mais les temps surcomposés ne font pas partie de mon dialecte et toutes leurs utilisations me font sursauter. "

Alors si c'est parler et écrire "dialectal" que d'utiliser le passé surcomposé, il y a plus de finesse et de subtilité  de l'expression chez ceux qui en font usage!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/20793)

Comment: Bonjour, de qui est la citation que vous mentionner ? Attention : vous ne semble pas répondre à la question posée.